# Fedora 17 LXDE missing man 2 and man 3 C functions

Tags: fedora, c, man

everyone.
I am using Fedora 17, and I need to refer to some C functions, but man 2 malloc or man 3 malloc ( malloc for example ) are not working. Also man (function) is not working too. Any clues? I am using Fedora 32bit, wiht LXDE environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are part of the man-pages package, maybe you didn't install that?